# how to use static file on css file with version in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I need help with a problem i just ran into while working with django static file.
so i downloaded this free html template that references  it css style as below:

````
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendor.bundle.css?ver=1930">
    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/vendor.bundle.css?ver=1930' %}"> ```

meanwhile in django template, i know to reference static files like css and js without the ?ver=1930  as below
````

```

now my problem is that if i reference as

````
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/vendor.bundle.css?ver=1930' %}"> ```

it doesn't load the css and if i take away the ?ver=1930 and load it like
````

```

it works but my css get broken. How do i fix this problem plssss.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your document structure. According to Django best practices, your document structure should be like this:

```
mysite/
    myapp/
        static/
            css
            js
            img
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        migrations/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
        manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        asgi.py
        wsgi.py
```

Add the css files to the static/css folder.

Your code would then be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/vendor.bundle.css' %}">
```

Read more on how to handle static files: [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/).

See how it is implemented in the polls tutorial:  [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial06/)

Answer (score 0):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/vendor.bundle.css' %}?ver=1930">`

Use like this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As variant

Write you custom storage, that will include version of static :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import StaticFilesStorage


class VersionedStaticFilesStorage(StaticFilesStorage):
    def url(self, name):
        url = super().url(name)
        return url + f'?version={settings.STATIC_VERSION}'
```